# if/else statements in a program that keeps score

Tags: java, if-statement, refactoring

I'm trying to redistribute my code that prints out a message that depends on the value I assign to a variable. I want to relocate the "your score is " + score part but I don't know how to because the score depends on the value I assign it, which is dependent on the total score. See below.

Note: Taking the "your score is " + score" part out of both sections and putting it at the end doesn't work because I want it to be before another section that is also dependent on the variables. I'll explain what I mean.

The output must be in the format of:

> Your score is *score*
>
> *another message based on the score*

```
int score;
if (total >= 50) {
    score = 100;
    System.out.println("Your score is " + score);
    System.out.println("Good job");


} else if (total >= 0) {
    score = 0;
    System.out.println("Your score is " + score);
    System.out.println("Play again?");

}
```

Comment: You question is not clear to me. What do you mean by "factor"?

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the similar part in a function:

```
void printMessage(int value) {
    System.out.println("Your score is " + score);
}
```

Then use it like:

```
int score;
if (total >= 50) {
    score = 100;
    printMessage(score);

} else if (total >= 0) {
    score = 0;
    printMessage(score);
}
```

Or, better yet:

```
int score;
if (total >= 50) {
    score = 100

} else if (total >= 0) {
    score = 0;
}

printMessage(score);
```

Comment: Please see the edits I just made above. Also, I'm trying to keep these functions in one method instead of having to create a new one. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @julianhill:  When you're refactoring, you're going to be introducing new methods.  This seems like an appropriate approach to achieve what you're looking for, unless you can be *pinpoint* specific that there is something that you want to accomplish *besides* having a common way to print the score.

Comment: @user8816734 Trying to shove everything into 1 method is a terrible approach. The second you start duplicating code, creating a new method is often the answer. Think hard about your restriction.

Comment: @user8816734 Also, can you elaborate on your edit? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Move out your if(total >= 0) and build a string to be printed at the end:

```
int score;
String msg;
if(total >= 0) {
    if (total >= 50) {
        score = 100;
        msg = "Good job";
    } else {
        score = 0;
        msg = "Play again?";
    }
    System.out.printf("Your score is %d\n%s", score, msg);
}
```

Comment: Please see the edits I just made above for more information. I realized that my initial question was not clear enough. I would love to see what additional feedback you can give me now that I've changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just print what the score is after the `if/else` statement.

```
System.out.print("Your score is ");
if (total >= 50) {
    score = 100;
    System.out.print(score);
    ...
} else if (total >= 0) {
    score = 0;
    System.out.print(score);
    ...
}
```

EDIT: I relocated the `"Your score is"` part, but it doesn't do anything to simplify the code.  I'm pretty sure your code is fine the way it is but this is another way to do it.

Comment: Please see the edits I just made above for more information. I realized that my initial question was not clear enough. I would love to see what additional feedback you can give me now that I've changed it. Otherwise, your code would work and is what I originally had in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can call two separate methods. One will return the score given a total and the other will return the message.

```
private void myMethod() {
  ...
  System.out.println("Your score is " + getScore(total));
  System.out.println(getMessage(total));
  ...
}

private String getScore(int total) {
  return total >= 50 ? 100 : total >= 0 ? 0 : -1;
}

private String getMessage(int total) {
  return total >= 50 ? "Good job" : total >= 0 ? "Play again?" : "";
}
```